# Passing an Environment Variable Through Alacarte?

Tags: gnome3, centos-7

I am trying pass an environment through alacrate in a launcher.

For example, I would like to run:
SWT_GTK3=0 /opt/eclipsecdt/eclipse

as a launcher.

But alarate grays out the okay button if I have SWT_GTK3=0.

Any idea how to get around it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a bash file with the content:

   `#!/bin/sh 
   SWT_GTK3=0
   /opt/eclipsecdt/eclipse`
2. make the file executable: chmod +x
3. run that new bash file from alacarte

second alternative would be to create an own .desktop file

1. create a new entry with alacarte
2. find the new file in /home/artur/.local/share/applications it will be named alacarte-made-x.desktop
3. edit the file

   `[Desktop Entry]
   Comment=
   Terminal=true
   Name=export
   Exec=/bin/sh -c "export SWT_GTK3=0; /opt/eclipsecdt/eclipse"
   Type=Application
   Icon=gnome-panel-launcher`

alacarte will not let you save that entry if you try to edit it with alacarte again but still that should be a valid .desktop file

For more information about what you can do with the .desktop file see the [GNOME Developer documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en)

Comment: Hmm...that's probably the only way.  Was hoping that alacarte supports environment variable..